# How to get like count from multiple facebook pages in a single request without login

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I need to take likes count from multiple facebook pages using php ,and it should be in a single request

thanks in advance

Comment: attempt to solve the problem. SO is not a code writing facility, you need to attempt the problem first

Answer (score 0):

Got a Solution with graph api
1)Create one facebook app 
2)Get APPIID and APPSECRETCODE
3) Curl the following url with these following params in url

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=pageid1,pageid2,pagid3&fields=likes&access_token=APPID|APPSECRETCODE